# When using * in bash how do I output to the same file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the command `convert -resize 1024X768  source.png dest.jpg` on a sequence of images. I need it to be applied to all the images which I can do by `convert -resize 1024X768  *.png` but I'd like to know how to supply the same filename as the destination.

I'm only using the convert command as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You can try with a `for` command line

Test with a 'dry run',

```
for i in *.png;do echo convert -resize 1024X768 "$i" "${i/.png}.jpg";done
```

and when its output looks good, remove `echo` and do the conversion,

```
for i in *.png;do convert -resize 1024X768 "$i" "${i/.png}.jpg";done
```

### Alternative with `find` and `rename`

If you want to avoid a loop in bash, you can use `find`,

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "*.png" -exec echo convert -resize 1024X768 {} {}.jpg \;
```

and when its output looks good, remove echo and do the conversion,

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "*.png" -exec convert -resize 1024X768 {} {}.jpg \;
```

After that you can use `rename` to make the target file names nicer (prune the clumsy double extension)

```
rename -n s/.png.jpg$/.jpg/ *.png.jpg
```

and when its output looks good, remove `-n` and do the real renaming,

```
rename s/.png.jpg$/.jpg/ *.png.jpg
```

There are probably ways to do this in one step (without renaming), but I don't know how. Maybe someone will chip in and describe a way to do it.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do it without a loop. Perhaps some fancy bash thing.

Comment: @user3927312, An alternative without an explicit loop is to use find and rename. I can add it to the answer, but I think the for loop is more straightforward.